# VueJS dynamic data + v-model

Tags: vue.js

In my data object, I need to push objects into an array called `editions`.

```js
data() {
  return {
    editions: []
  }
}
```

To do this, I am dynamically creating a form based on some predetermined field names.  Here's where the problem comes in. I can't get v-model to cooperate.  I was expecting to do something like this:

```html
<div v-for="n in parseInt(total_number_of_editions)">
  <div v-for="field in edition_fields">
    <input :type="field.type" v-model="editions[n][field.name]" />
  </div>
</div>
```

But that isn't working.  I get a `TypeError: _vm.editions[n] is undefined`.  The strange thing is that if I try this: `v-model="editions[n]"`... it works, but I don't have the property name.  So I don't understand how `editions[n]` could be undefined.  This is what I'm trying to end up with in the data object:

```js
editions: [
  {
    name: "sample name",
    status: "good"
  },
  ... 
]
```

Can anyone advise on how to achieve this?

Comment: You could initialize your data according to the expected structure, so v-model could bind to existing properties.

Comment: @yuriy636 But how do I do that if I have an arbitrary number of array elements?

Comment: Use the edition_fields variable to create the proper editions property in your data object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that isn't working. I get a `TypeError: _vm.editions[n] is undefined`.

`editions` is initially an empty array, so `editions[n]` is `undefined` for all `n`. Vue is essentially doing this:

```js
const editions = []
const n = 1
console.log(editions[n]) // => undefined
```

> The strange thing is that if I try this: `v-model="editions[n]"`... it works

When you use `editions[n]` in `v-model`, you're essentially creating the array item at index `n` with a new value. Vue is doing something similar to this:

```js
const editions = []
const n = 2
editions[n] = 'foo'
console.log(editions) // => [ undefined, undefined, "foo" ]
```

---

To fix the root problem, initialize `editions` with an object array, whose length is equal to `total_number_of_editions`:

```js
const newObjArray = n => Array(n)             // create empty array of `n` items
                          .fill({})           // fill the empty holes
                          .map(x => ({...x})) // map the holes into new objects

this.editions = newObjArray(this.total_number_of_editions)
```

If `total_number_of_editions` could change dynamically, use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the variable, and update `editions` according to the new count.

```js
const newObjArray = n => Array(n).fill({}).map(x => ({...x}))

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    const edition_fields = [
      { type: 'number', name: 'status' },
      { type: 'text', name: 'name' },
    ];
    
    return {
      total_number_of_editions: 5,
      editions: [],
      edition_fields
    }
  },
  watch: {
    total_number_of_editions: {
      handler(total_number_of_editions) {
        const count = parseInt(total_number_of_editions)

        if (count === this.editions.length) {
          // ignore
          
        } else if (count < this.editions.length) {
          this.editions.splice(count)

        } else {
          const newCount = count - this.editions.length
          this.editions.push(...newObjArray(newCount))
        }
      },
      immediate: true,
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label>Number of editions
    <input type="number" min=0 v-model="total_number_of_editions">
  </label>

  <div><pre>total_number_of_editions={{total_number_of_editions}}
editions={{editions}}</pre></div>

  <fieldset v-for="n in parseInt(total_number_of_editions)" :key="n">
    <div v-for="field in edition_fields" :key="field.name+n">
      <label>{{field.name}}{{n-1}}
        <input :type="field.type" v-if="editions[n-1]" v-model="editions[n-1][field.name]" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```